# Sending a '$param' in a post request

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, sanitize

I am currently writing an angular, express, mongoose(monogodb) app and there is this strange behavior I am running into.

I want to send a mongoose query to the server side so in the client side I write the query as so

```
var query = {
'_id' : {'$in' : ['1958929ef']}
};
```

This gets passed into express.js however, when I console.log it the '$in' param is not there.

I get...

```
var query = {
'_id' : {}
}
```

When I change '$in' to just 'in' i can see there is no problem.

Why does this happen? Is it because of sanitize? (i removed the sanitize module from angular and the issue still occurs)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1463

Comment: The above comment is precisely why - Angular is stripping the parameters which start with "$".